# Issues installing frida with pip

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pip, frida

I have python 3.12 and the latest version of pip installed on windows 10, but when I run the command:

```bash
pip install frida-tools
```

In Command Prompt, I get the following error messages:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/frida-tools/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/frida-tools/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/frida-tools/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/frida-tools/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/frida-tools/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement frida-tools (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for frida-tools
```

What could the issue be?

I tried looking for an answer on the internet but couldn't find anything regarding this specific case.

Comment: Make sure you are using the 64 bit version of Python as Frida has dropped 32 bit support.

Comment: I'm using the 64 bit version

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct Python version? Use `which pip.exe` respectively `which python.exe` to check.

Comment: I'm on windows and `which` doesn't appear to be a command. Could it be that there's no support yet for Python 3.12?

Comment: Sorry I have installed Linux command-line tools on Windows and forgot this, on Windows the native command is `where` instead of `which`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out what my issue was, although I'm not entirely sure why it affects my ability to install packages via pip.

I had previously set an SSLKEYLOGFILE environment variable on my system and later on renamed its corresponding folder. After deleting said variable I was able to successfully run the frida install command.

Albeit niche, I hope this is of use to someone.

Comment: Confirming this worked for me as well.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that you mentioned using pip version 3.12 with Python. I wanted to clarify that pip3 is the recommended package manager for Python 3.4 and later versions, and it is designed to work with packages that are compatible with these versions. Before proceeding, ensure that your pip is up-to-date by running the following command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

After that, you can try installing the **frida-tools** package using the command:

```
python -m pip install frida-tools
```

Additionally, You can find more information on the [official Frida website](https://frida.re/), and you can access the [code](https://github.com/frida/frida) on GitHub. I hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. Unfortunately after running these commands I still get the same error. Also interestingly, after running the first command, the output is "Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\python312\lib\site-packages (23.2.1)", followed by the same warning error messages "WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/pip/". Perhaps this could shed some insight on the issue

Comment: I'm using MacOS instead of Windows 10, but I was able to successfully install frida-tools using the command 'pip3 install frida-tools' in the terminal without any issues. However, I believe there may be a problem with your system path. Can you check if pip is included in your system path? If not, you can try running 'pip list' in your terminal to see if it's installed

Comment: It does appear to be installed and in my system path

Comment: To clarify, are you using PowerShell in your Windows 10 environment? I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDaw4y1ybJ4) helpful

Comment: I tried on PowerShell and got the same errors unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried following the installation instructions on Frida's website? According to the [docs](https://frida.re/docs/installation/), you can install Frida-tools version [16.1.11](https://frida.re/news/2024/01/12/frida-16-1-11-released/) by running the command 'pip install frida-tools=16.1.11' in your terminal. The issue you're experiencing may be related to Python's installation path. There's a similar issue reported on GitHub that might be helpful: [frida/frida#1142](https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/1142)